# How to return a smart pointer to a member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm attempting to create an accessor for a class member variable using smart pointers. Here's the code:

```
class MyResource
{
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyResource> getResource();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyResource> resource;
};

std::unique_ptr<MyResource> MyClass::getResource()
{
    return this->resource;
}
```

The error I get trying to compile this:

> cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Adding `.get` to `this->resource` of course doesn't work because the return type changes.

Should I not be using a unique_ptr here? Is this just a syntax issue? Am I totally on the wrong track?

**my background with smart pointers:**
I've been using plain-old-pointers for a couple of years now in part because I can't find a solid explanation of when to use which types of smart pointers and how to go about using them. I'm tired of making excuses, so I'm just diving in. I think I understand what smart pointers are and why to use them, but I understand very little of the details. At the moment I'm totally lost in [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119962/smart-pointers-when-where-and-how) [endless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242320/smart-pointers-why-use-them-and-which-to-use) [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) [smart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr) [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576922/pimpl-shared-ptr-or-unique-ptr).

Comment: you shouldn't be using a unique pointer here.  Return it by value or make it a shared pointer.

Comment: @dwcanillas Or return it by reference or by raw pointer.

Comment: @Angew yep, exactly.  The whole point of unique pointers are that they are unique, there is one pointer to one object.

Comment: @OP You are aware that `std::unique_ptr<MyResource> MyClass::getResource()` would transfer ownership to the caller? That's most probably not what you wan't, unless designing a factory.

Comment: Note: You can not transfer ownership without a std::move (std::forward), see Barry's answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most important thing to understand about smart pointers is that the "pointer" aspect is not the fundamental part of their semantics. Smart pointers exist to represent **ownership**. Ownership is defined as the responsibility for cleanup.

A unique pointer says: "I am the sole owner of the pointee. I will destroy it when I go out of scope."

A shared pointer says: "I am one of a group of friends who share the responsibility for the pointee. The last of us to go out of scope will destroy it."

(In a modern C++ program,) A raw pointer or reference says: "I do not own the pointee, I merely observe it. Someone else is responsible for destroying it."

In your case, using a `unique_ptr` for the member type means that `MyClass` owns the `MyResource` object. If the getter is supposed to transfer ownership (that is, if the `MyClass` is giving up the resource to whoever called the getter), returning a `unique_ptr` is appropriate (and you'll have to `return std::move(resource);` to make the ownership transfer explicit).

If the getter is *not* supposed to give up the ownership (which I consider the likely scenario), just return a plain old pointer (if returning a null pointer is an option) or a plain old reference (if returning null is not an option).

Comment: While the other answer has received more votes, this answer was the most helpful to me personally because of the explanation. Now I think (I gorram hope) that I finally understand this.

Comment: @David Which is precisely why SO has both the concepts of voting and accepting :-) Happy to have helped.

Comment: For the third case, we will soon also have `std::experimental::observer_ptr`.

Answer (score 22):

You have several options here, depending on the semantics you wish your class to observe.

1. You want to give up ownership of your resource:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<MyResource> MyClass::releaseResource() {
       return std::move(this->resource);
   }
   ```
2. You want to maintain unique ownership, but have somebody else use it:

   ```
   MyResource& MyClass::getResource() {
       assert(this->resource);
       return *(this->resource);
   }
   ```
3. You want to *share* ownership, so the resource doesn't get destroyed if `MyClass` goes out of scope: switch everything to `std::shared_ptr<MyResource>` and still return by value.

Comment: You were faster, have a +1 :-)